# Combined Forward and Backward analysis in soot

Tags: java, compiler-construction, soot

I want to perform Data Flow analysis in Soot. But the nature of my analysis is that it will perform one iteration of Forward analysis and then one iteration of Backward analysis using the dataflow values computed in the Forward analysis. These two iteration turns to be single iteration of my analysis technique.

Is this possible in Soot as it provides only forward, backward and forwardbranch flow analysis?

If it is not then what changes I need to do in Soot framework. If there are other tools available for dataflow analysis in JAVA then could someone just tell me.

Thanks in advance,

Mandar

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's entirely possible. You might want to look at our paper on Boomerang to see how such an analysis might be implemented:
http://www.bodden.de/research/publications/

FlowDroid also uses a similar method of implementation and it's available online:
https://blogs.uni-paderborn.de/sse/tools/flowdroid/